# Self invoking function interfering with window.onload unless

Tags: javascript, dom, onload, self-invoking-function

I have a `window.onload` function right before a **self invoking function.**

```
window.onload = function(){
console.log(document.getElementById("one")); //returns null
}

(function selfExecuting(){
    console.log("hi")
}());
```

The HTML is simply:

```
<div id="one">hi</div>
```

When I try to find a DOM element in the window.onload function, it's returning "`null`". **UNLESS** I add a line of code which stores an *unused* variable.

```
window.onload = function(){
console.log(document.getElementById("one")); //now, this returns "<div id="one">hi</div>"
}

var unusedVar = "var"; // This unused variable makes the code work

(function selfExecuting(){
    console.log("hi")
}());
```

Can someone help me understand why it's working like this? What is this unused line of code doing? I have a feeling this has something to do with how self invoking functions work, but I'm not sure.

A note: I tried to share this as a fiddle, but it resulted in slightly different console logs. The console logs I'm getting are with Chrome if that makes a difference.

Comment: You need to add a semicolon.

Comment: Not reproducable in: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OrORRR

Comment: @SLaks that was it! I feel like a dunce! I always thought semi colons were kind of optional in javascript. Sometimes I leave them out and nothing happens.

Comment: Don't omit semicolons until you understand [where](https://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons) [you need them](https://blog.izs.me/2010/12/an-open-letter-to-javascript-leaders-regarding)

Comment: @Bergi ok thanks everyone. Something I definitely need to look into now.